# How to find NSTemporaryDirectory in finder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am using NSTemporaryDirectory() and globallyUniqueString to create a temporary directory and a unique file path. I will be saving a file in the temp directory and I want to know and verify the contents of the file that gets saved in the temporary directory.

```
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]] isDirectory:YES];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:directoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

NSURL *fileURL = [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:uniqueFileName];

[loadedModelTemp writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

I have checked the Xcode derived data but couldn't find the folder. Is this folder even accesssible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking the question quickly without checking the house first. The file gets saved in `/var/` folder. I just NSlogged the `fileURL` variable and got the whole path. I

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer if it answered your question (even if you answered your own question ;)).

Comment: I have to wait for another day to accept it as my answer :|